# How can I make gcc search for #include <...> files in the current source file's directory?

Tags: gcc, build-process

When a file contains an include line like this:

```
#include "name.h"
```

gcc (and other C compilers) search for the file "name.h" in the directory containing the file being compiled.  This does not by default happen if the line looks like this:

```
#include <name.h>
```

Is there an option to gcc to make it behave this way in the latter case too?  As noted [in the gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html), "-I. searches the compiler's current working directory for header files. That may or may not be the same as the directory containing the current file."  In the case I am working on (importing external code that used a build environment that automatically added the containing directory to the search path into a system that doesn't have such a build facility), the current directory is unfortunately not the same.  What can I do?  I'd rather not have to specifically modify the files...

Comment: Try `gcc  -isystem` Instead of `gcc -I` ?

Comment: Cannot say, when it changed. But many many years ago, the specification said, that the difference between ``#include ".."`` and ``#include <...>`` was only the order of searching. In the former case, source file directory first, then other search paths, in the latter case, vice versa. I noticed, that some when in the past 15 years this appears to have changed...

Comment: What worked great for me usually was: Never use ``#include "..."``, never use relative include paths (``#include <a/b.h>``) and have a package organization ``package/scr, package/include/public, package/include/private``. Then integrators only have to add the ``package/include/public`` paths to their build configuration.

Comment: @BitTickler Unfortunately, the source is coming from a third party and will need to track their changes, so I'd rather not have to change it that way.  I've decided to abandon using my IDE's build system and switch to a custom makefile; that way I can add the directories explicitly as required.

Comment: @Jules You have more options which might make you happier. Use CMake and you might have saved a lot of manual make file hacking. Build the third party code as a lib and just copy the public headers and the third party libs where you need them. Then for your IDE-based code, simply link the third party libs.